# Mean of two time series

Tags: time-series, mean, covariance

I'm trying to estimate the covariance of two time series using the formula
[image: Covariance]

where `X` and `Y` are two time series.
I don't understand how to calculate the value of the first term: does that mean I have to calculate the mean of the means, or do I have to multiply the `X` serie by the `Y` serie, and then calculate the mean?
If so, how do you multiply two series?

Forgive me if I'm asking a silly question, I'm new to this subject and it is pretty confusing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\overline{XY}$ stands for the empirical mean of $XY$ where $XY$ is a random variable that equals the product of random variables $X$ and $Y$. That is, 
$$
\overline{XY}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i
$$ 
for a sample of size $n$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th observation of $X$ and $y_i$ is the $i$th observation of $Y$. Hence, you multiply the two vectors element by element, sum them up and divide by the number of elements in one vector.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. But I think you forgot to divide by n in the formula!